# Cheerio cannot scrape table with no ID or className, but paths are being accessed correctly

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

The item I am trying to access in the following HTML is "GMV DLL VERSION2"

```
    <div class="container content">

  <main>
    <h2 id="rpcs--gmv-dll-version"><a href="/artifacts/vistaRPC%20documentation/TableOfContent">RPCs</a> → GMV DLL VERSION</h2>

<h3 id="vista-file-8994">VISTA File 8994</h3>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>property</th>
      <th>value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>label</td>
      <td>GMV DLL VERSION2</td>
```

I am trying to scrape this website (http://vistadataproject.info/artifacts/vistaRPC%20documentation/GMV%20DLL%20VERSION)

and output it into a text file. I successfully did a test run with reddit.com. However I cannot seem to get this page to get even a single element off of it. To test it, even before tackling the table I've been trying to scrape some elements that come quite early (in top area) of the page.

The lack of classNames and Id in the tables is tricky enough, but not being able to get even the title text is really making me wonder what is going on. Any input will be appreciated. 
    request(`http://vistadataproject.info/artifacts/vistaRPC%20documentation/GMV%20DLL%20VERSION`, (err, res, body) => {

```
if (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
  }
  console.log('Status: ' + res.statusCode);

  const $ = cheerio.load(body);

  $('header.masthead > div.container').each(( index, tr ) => {
    // var children = $(this).children();
    const tableData = $(this).find('a.logo').text();
console.log("Table Contents: " + tableData);

fs.appendFileSync('test.txt', tableData + '\n' + 'Captured');


});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that 'masthead' is a class name, not an id. Same deal with 'container' and 'logo'. So you need to adjust your selector accordingly:

```
$('header.masthead > div.container').each(( index, tr ) => {
```

However, that only gets you the header information, which does not include the tables containing the 'property => value' data. For that information you just need to look for child tables under the '<main>' tag.

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid that I was experimenting when I pasted that, but I've yet to head to see any evidence that its reaching the text regardless of which character I use.

Comment: Yes, my original 'path' was 'div.container.content > main > table > tbody > tr' but because I was being so unsuccessful, I was trying something much simpler just to see if I can get ANYTHING.  So far, no success.  Regardless of hashtags/pound sign usage for id or periods for classNames